# Tranparent object is hidden behind tranparent object

Tags: transparency

i have a problem about transparent object.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As the pictures show, the part of the bottle behind glass can not be seen.

I made the models in Blender. It would be used in AFrame.

Maybe someone can tell me, what is the reason and how can I solve that?

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: perhaps go into Properties > Render > Light Paths > Transparency and try to increase the factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global collapse of hidden faces is enabled. Just disable it and solve the problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for you help. But disable Backface Culling dosen't solve the problem. DoubleSided is also on. I still have no ideal about the reason.
Demo: http://webvr.virtualskillslab.de/
with ctrl + alt + i can enter the edit mode

Comment: Maybe A-Frame or gltf2.0 don't support double sided or backface culling disable?